# Which PowerShell commands can be run to export specific DLs with the list of owners and members?

Tags: powershell, ms-office, powershell-remoting, export-csv, distribution-list

can anyone help me with PowerShell commands so that I can pull up CSV specific DLs with the list of its owners and members . As an example DLs start with classification or C&T ? Any assistance will be appreciated.

Tried exporting CSV through admin center but there is no option to appear members as well

Comment: See Section 4 : https://o365info.com/manage-distribution-groups-by-using/

Comment: Export _from where_? Active Directory? Office 365?